# Apenas segundos em input

Tags: html

Como faço para que no input seja possivel selecionar apenas segundos?

Não preciso das horas, nem dos minutos, apenas de tempo em segundos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque `type="number", max="60" e min="0"` no input, ou configure o [max](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp) conforme quiser se for um tempo maior que um minuto

```html
    <input type="number" max="60" min="0"/>
```

Comment: Lembrando que não existe "60 segundos".. os segundos vão de 0 a 59, se é que entendi a pergunta :D

Comment: Correto @Sam, coloquei 60 pois não sei qual é o objetivo, lembrando que para fazer operação matemáticas com segundos, precisamos de 60 segundos para representar 1 minuto.

Comment: É faz sentido, mas a pergunta é tão vazia que não se sabe o que o AP deseja realmente. Eu imagino que ele esteja se referindo ao input tipo `datetime-local`, mas não dá pra ter certeza.